# Compatibility of WinAPI with Windows XP

Tags: winapi

I wrote a console application to collect event logs using event API. It works fine in Windows 8. Since Windows Log format has been changed to binary XML from normal binary, I got this doubt. Whether my application will work in Windows XP or Not?

Comment: Please show the code you're using and you can easily check MSDN for information about compatibility for any WinAPI functions you are using.

Comment: Even once you've checked it formally, you need to test

Comment: MSDN lies about compatibility unfortunately.

Comment: @Jonathan Lying is a little strong. They no longer support XP and no longer account for it in docs.

Comment: Using VS-2015, I haven't been able to make a simple hello-world console program which runs on XP. I gave up on it quickly though, I am sure I did something wrong.

Comment: @David "misleads" then.

Comment: @JonathanPotter: The MSDN is neither lying nor misleading anyone about the compatibility. The documented contract is valid for the Windows versions listed under *minimum supported client/server*. Windows XP is no longer supported, and the contract may or may not hold. If you want to know, whether any particular API is available on Windows XP, [modify WINVER and _WIN32_WINNT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sehtctf.aspx) and have the compiler tell you.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani - under project settings, select C/C++ -> Code Generation -> Runtime library.  Change from "Multi-threaded  DLL" to just "Multithreaded".  I don't think the latest MSVCRT DLLs run on XP, but statically compiled binaries should still work.  Disclaimer: I haven't tried it, but I'd expect it to work.  WINVER define might also influence compatibility.